# Regex for simple password validation in PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I'm trying to validate a password with PHP and I want to use the same Regex with Javascript, In my PHP I'm getting error when I'm trying to use the following regex.`(Warning: filter_var(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 14)`

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\]\[\?\/<~#`!@\$%\^&\*\(\)\+=\}\|:\";\',>\{]{4,20}$/

if (!filter_var($password,FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\]\[\?\/<~#`!@\$%\^&\*\(\)\+=\}\|:\";\',>\{]{4,20}$/")))){
    $errors .= "Please enter a valid password.";
}
```

I want the password to have `0-9`,`a-zA-Z` and these characters `] [ ? / < ~ #  ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) + = } | : " ; ' , > { space` plus `

I want to use the regex for front and back ends.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html). If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I'm hashing the password in my user class, `$password = password_hash($user_passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Comment: The only problem was the hyphen, right? Place it at the end of the character class, and in JS and PHP you won't have to escape it. Use `^[a-zA-Z0-9_\]\[?\/<~#\`!@$%^&*()+=}|:\";\',>{ -]{4,20}$`. I see your regex is missing a space, I added it, too. However, the hyphen is missing from your list of allowed characters. Something does not click here.

Comment: Does it mean my regex works for you? Shall I post an answer then?

Comment: @stribizhev, yes it does post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\]\[?\/<~#`!@$%^&*()+=}|:\";\',>{ -]{4,20}$
                                             ^^
```

Note the "smart" position of the hyphen at the end of the character class, and in JS and PHP you won't have to escape it.

I see your regex is missing a space, I added it, too.

Note that inside a character class, a lot of special characters are treated as literals, and do not have to be escaped. I removed escape symbols from those that do not need escaping.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this "modular" regEx

`/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/.test(password)`

this password should have:

1. `(?=.*\d)` = digits
2. `(?=.*[a-z])` = small letters
3. `(?=.*[A-Z])` = cap. letters
4. `.{8,}` = at least 8 chars long

**Special chars part:** taken from one of the answers above thanks @stribizhev

5. `` (?=.*[?\/<~#`!@$%^&*()+=}|:\";\',>{ -]) `` = special chars

So you end up with:

`` /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[?\/<~#`!@$%^&*()+=}|:\";\',>{ -])/.test(password) ``

to force minimal lenght .{n,} n = lenght

`` /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[?\/<~#`!@$%^&*()+=}|:\";\',>{ -]).{8,}/.test(pass) ``

Comment: I want to include the other mentioned characters.

Comment: just add them as additional condition (?=.*[%_])

Comment: @TurnTheTables to test your regex you can use the console in chrome dev-tools ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\]\[\?\/\<\~\#\`\@\$%\^&\*\(\)\+=\}\|:\";\'\,>\{]{4,20}$/
```

You had an un-escaped hyphen in your first character set, and you needed to escape the comma.

Edit: Escaped a few other metacharacters.

Comment: Thanks but you are missing the hyphen.

Comment: @Turn The Tables I took it out intentionally because it looked like an error. I used the list of characters you posted underneath your code, which did not include the hyphen. You might want to update your original question.